# How can I hide Validate button in account.invoice based on state in another module?

Tags: odoo, openerp-7

I need to hide Validate button in account.invoice based on status selection field that exists in another module which has state of financial close.

Hide validate button if status is financial_close

```
<button name="invoice_open" states="draft" string="Validate" class="oe_highlight" groups="base.group_user"/>
```

another module that contains financial close state

```
'status': fields.selection([
            ('open', 'Open'),
            ('operation_close', 'Operation Closed'),
            ('financial_close', 'Financial Closed'),
            ('cancel', 'Cancel'),
        ], string="Status"),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follw these step:

1. Create `Many2one`  in `account.invoice` with the **another module**.
2. Create a related field `mystatus`  in  `account.invoice` with `Many2one` previously created .
3. Inherit the  parent view[ `invoice_form`] of **invoice_open**.
4. Place your relate field:`mystatus` on the view  Like :`<field name="mystatus"/>`.
5. Use `xpath` and `postion= attributes`

Here is the code snippet :

```
 <xpath expr="//button[@name='invoice_open']" position="attributes">
 <attribute name="attrs">{'invisible':[('mystatus','=', 'open')]}</attribute>
```

This may help in your case

Comment: The button definition for invoice_open uses the states attribute. So you have to care and decide if you need to override that to. Odoo will combine states and attrs.